# Can Java websocket server ignore large messages rather than closing the connection?

Tags: tomcat8, java-websocket

Specs:

- Java 1.8
- Tomcat 8.0.39
- WebSocket API 1.1

Occasionally one of my clients will send a large payload (greater than the default 8192 byte buffer size) and when this happens the server kills the connection with a CloseReason of [1009 (Too Large)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/websocket/Constants.html#STATUS_MESSAGE_TOO_LARGE). I'd rather configure the server to ignore the occasional large message rather than nuking the connection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for Tomcat 8, this one is for binary messages:

> The default buffer size for binary messages is 8192 bytes. This may be changed for a web application by setting the servlet context initialization parameter org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize to the desired value in bytes.

This is also the same for text messages:

> The default buffer size for text messages is 8192 bytes. This may be changed for a web application by setting the servlet context initialization parameter org.apache.tomcat.websocket.textBufferSize to the desired value in bytes.

Found here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html

If you are using `WebSocketContainer` there is also the following methods: `setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize` and `setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize`.

Found here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/websocketapi/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html